# Do I have a dependent clause or independent?

Tags: compounds, complex-sentences

> Sam got dressed, and it was time for school.

Or

> Sam got dressed because it was time for school.

Both the sentences sound correct to me.

It seems the clause "it was time for school" can be thought of as an independent clause or as a dependent clause based on its use. Am I right? I would be grateful if anyone could explain this further.

Answer (score 2):

> [1] *Sam got dressed,* [*and it was time for school*].
>
> [2] *Sam got dressed because* [*it was time for school*].

The bracketed expression in [1] is a main clause. It is not dependent on any other element in the sentence.

But in [2] it is a subordinate clause. There is no internal marker of subordination: it is shown to be subordinate by virtue of its function in the larger construction.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems the clause "it was time for school" can be thought of as an independent clause or as a dependent clause based on it's use. Am I right?

Yes, but you need to think about the **function** of *and [it was time for school.]*.

[Sam got dressed], and [it was time for school.] are clearly independent clauses:  In your mind you have made the link between the two that is not there in the clauses.

We do not know how old Sam is. He could be getting dressed because he is going to a wedding. He could know that [it was time for school] because he could hear children's voices.

In *[Sam got dressed], **because** [it was time for school]*, because [it was time for school] tells us that the reason for Sam's dressing has something to do with the time that school opens - He could be a student or a teacher - but whatever he is, school opening time has a significance for him.